# Tab a scripts output

Tags: bash, tabs

I want command output to turn from:

```sh
really
long
line
```

to output like this:

```sh
    really
    long
    line
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sed 's/^/\t/'` ?

Comment: yes! Is there a way to change the tab length?

Comment: add more `\t` 's ?

Comment: the tab length is a single character, how it looks will depend in your terminal. you can change it using `tabs -4` though.

Comment: I mean, less tabs, like 4 spaces instead of 8

Comment: @JuanR is it possible to set tabs temporarily in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab width can be changed using the `tabs` command:

For exaple:

```
root@d6cf49e7d107:/# tabs -4 && echo -e "hello\tworld"
hello   world                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
root@d6cf49e7d107:/# tabs -2 && echo -e "hello\tworld"
hello world                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
root@d6cf49e7d107:/# tabs +8 && echo -e "hello\tworld"
hello   world                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
root@d6cf49e7d107:/# tabs +20 && echo -e "hello\tworld"
hello               world
```

Update: The setting is not persistent. i.e.: It will be valid until the session is closed, this means it is safe to use it inside a script.

Comment: Can you temporarily set tab lengths, so a script can be for instance, 4, and terminal tab length would be 8?

Comment: yes (I updated my answer to reflect that fact)